# C++: For a class that inherited multiple classes, how to inherit certain attributes from one class and others from the other?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, c++98, diamond-problem

Can someone help me understand how a class that inherits from multiple classes can retain certain attribute values from one class and other certain attribute values from another.

*(and how would one do so for certain functions as well)*

---

Here is a bit of code to describe the problem.

It's a situation where there is a diamond inheritance structure:

---

------------- Base

----------/---------------\

-------/--------------------\

--- Mother-------------Father

---\ -----------------------/

------\ ------------------/

---------\ -------------/

------------ Child

---

The goal is to inherit from both the `Father` class & the `Mother` class (& evidently from the `Base` class) but to retain the `y` value of the `Father` and the `z` value from the `Mother`. I just don't know how to do that.

I believe that the problem with the following code is that the order in which the constructors are called make it so that the `Father` constructor overwrites the `z` value that the `Mother` constructor right before it initialized.

I'm thinking that I might have to make a special `private`/`protected` `Father` constructor that doesn't initialize the `z` and a special `private`/`protected` `Mother` constructor that doesn't initialize the `y` and explicitly call those constructors.

But idk if that's the right way of doing it or if there's a better way. Does anyone know a better way ?

---

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {

    protected:

        int x;
        int y;
        int z;

    public:

        Base(void) : x(0) {}

};

/* — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — —  */

class Father
    : public virtual Base {

    public:

        Father(void) : Base() {
            y = 1;
            z = 1;
        }
};

/* — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — —  */

class Mother
    : public virtual Base {

    public:

        Mother(void) : Base() {
            y = 2;
            z = 2;
        }
};

/* — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — —  */

class Child
    : public Mother, public Father {

    public:

        Child(void) : Base() {

            y = Father::y;
            z = Mother::z;
        }

        int getX() { return x; };
        int getY() { return y; };
        int getZ() { return z; };
};

/* — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — —  */

int main() {

    Child newborn;

    std::cout << newborn.getX() << std::endl
              << newborn.getY() << std::endl
              << newborn.getZ() << std::endl;

    return (0);
}

/* — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — — —  */
```

---

```
Output:

0
1
1

——— VS ———

Desired Output:

0
1
2
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem I can not see what are you trying to solve.

Comment: Usually virtual bases are pure, abstract, with zero data members.

Comment: You are not calling the constructors of Mother and Father in Child. The values Father::y and Mother::z are uninitialized.

Comment: @Nico238 , they (the default constructors of `Mother` followed by that of `Father`) are called, implicitly. Whereas you can see that the constructor (which happens to be the default one) of the `Base` class is **explicitly** called.

Comment: The example is bogus.  A child cannot be both a mother and a father.

Comment: You just don't. If all you want is values then you can inherit the base and setup static values in the other two classes as defaults. If you need anything more than that then I think you'll need to show us your real world problem.

Comment: @paddy ... Ever heard of multiple inheritance ? C++ supports it. Try running the code ?

Comment: @George , but what if I don't want to make them static, I want them private to the class object and non-constant ... If you don't know how, its fine but don't avoid the problem please.

Comment: On paper, in school, and in books, multiple inheritance and nested inheritance  concrete classes looks appealing. In practice, it's hard to get right and difficult to maintain.  Interface inheritance can be an awesome thing, but for concrete classes, I tend to recommend designing in terms of "has a" instead of "is a".

Comment: @AymenTM indeed, Base Father and Mother are called once. In my test Father is called after Mother so it overwrite the z attribute

Comment: Aymen, where Paddy is likely going is the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which basically comes down to don't inherit where it doesn't make sense. Inheritance establishes an [is-a relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a). Child is a mother. This doesn't make much sense. Child is a father. This also doesn't make much sense. Child being a mother and a father at the same time doesn't make sense. You can do it sure, but you can also `int x= x;` and `int *x = null; *x = 42;` Just because you can do it doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @AymenTM Solving a problem in the right way is not avoiding it. "I want them private to the class object and non-constant ..." My suggestion doesn't break either of those two conditions.

Comment: You inherit everything the base classes make inheritable. You don't get to choose.

Comment: Beside `Father::x` or `Mother::x` you can use `using Father::x` inside the `Child` to make that member variable as the default for `x` inside the child (and you can even change the access modifiers `public`/`protected`/`private` of inherited members with this method). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration In Class Definition

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it this way.

The [virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) is aimed to not duplicate the members.

Knowing this:

- `Child::x`, `Mother::x` and `Father::x` are **exactly** the same variable
- `Child::y`, `Mother::y` and `Father::y` are **exactly** the same variable
- `Child::z`, `Mother::z` and `Father::z` are **exactly** the same variable

These are just three ways to access the same variable on the memory stack. So when you writes `y = Father::y;`, it is exactly the same as if you had written `y = y;`, and so on for the other variables.

---

**If you really want to do that without changing your design**, perhaps you can store in `Father` and in `Mother` an extra variable which contains the preset you want and just give it to `Child` through **scope resolution**.

`Father`, `Mother` and `Child` could look like:

```
class Father : public virtual Base
{
    protected:
        int preset;

    public:
        Father() : preset(1)
        {
            y = preset;
            z = preset;
        }
};

class Mother : public virtual Base
{
    protected:
        int preset;

    public:
        Mother() : preset(2)
        {
            y = preset;
            z = preset;
        }
};

class Child : public Mother, public Father
{
    public:
        Child()
        {
            y = Father::preset;
            z = Mother::preset;
        }

        int getX() const {return x;}
        int getY() const {return y;}
        int getZ() const {return z;}
};
```

And it should do the trick with few changes.

---

To conclude, I would say that for each problem that requires multiple inheritance, there is at least one other solution (a better design) which does not imply multiple inheritance (This is only my opinion).

So I would advise you to reconsider your design instead of using the workaround I proposed here.

Comment: I needed to do this because I have constrains to follow where I need at the same time just create only one time the base class, still using the values from specific parents. Thanks. Classic "diamond problem" inheritance.